# Error lib sprintf nodejs restify mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, restify

I'm trying to run a server node with restify. I have this error:

```
throw (new Error('too few args to sprintf'));
```

My server node code is:

```
function callPost(req, res, next) {
   var user = {};
   user.nombre = req.params.nombre;
   user.apellido = req.params.apellido;
   user.email = req.params.email;
   user.telefono = req.params.telefono;
   user.dirig = req.params.dirig;
   user.mensaje = req.params.mensaje;
//user.idform = req.params.idform;   user.fecha = req.params.fecha;

   var formu = "2";

   var sql = "call sp_contacto(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   connection.query(sql, [user.nombre, user.apellido, user.email, user.telefono, user.dirig, user.mensaje, formu, user.fecha],
      function (error, success) {
         if (error) throw error;
         console.log(success);
         res.send(200, success.insertId);
      }
   );
}
```

and my stored procedure is:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_contacto`(

    IN nom      VARCHAR(100),
    IN ape      VARCHAR(100),
    IN mail     VARCHAR(100),
    IN tel      VARCHAR(100),
    IN dirigido VARCHAR(100),
    IN maj      TEXT,
    IN id_form  INT,
    IN p_fecha  DATE

) BEGIN

    DECLARE p_idvisitante int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE existe int DEFAULT 0;

    select count_visit(nom, mail) into existe;

    IF existe = 0 THEN    
        CALL insert_visitante(nom, ape, mail, tel);
        select id_visit(nom, mail) into p_idvisitante;
        CALL insert_visit_form_selec(p_idvisitante, id_form, 6, p_fecha, dirigido);     
        CALL insert_visit_form_selec(p_idvisitante, id_form, 7, p_fecha, msj);
        CALL insert_form_visit(p_idvisitante, id_form);
    ELSE
        select id_visit(nom, mail) into p_idvisitante;
        CALL insert_visit_form_selec(p_idvisitante, id_form, 6, p_fecha, dirigido);
        CALL insert_visit_form_selec(p_idvisitante, id_form, 7, p_fecha, msj);
        CALL insert_form_visit(p_idvisitante, id_form);
    END IF;

END
```

What is the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions:

**console.log(error);**

before of:

res.send(200, success.insertId);